# Stub error (2002): can't find rtm.exe

Tags: ensamblador

Estoy conociendo el lenguaje ensamblador y tengo que hacer una pequeña practica pero me sale un error.
Voy a compilar un programa desde cmd, y crear un .exe a partir de un .obj

Hasta aquí todo bien, si crea el ejemplo.obj

```
C:\Ensamblador>TASM ejemplo.asm
```

Pero cuando ejecuto lo siguiente ya sale el error

```
C:\Ensamblador>TLINK ejemplo.obj
Stub error (2002): can't find rtm.exe
```

y no puedo crear el ejemplo.exe
En mi carpeta ensamblador están los archivos TASM.EXE, TD.EXE, TLINK.EXE.
Trabajo en maquina virtual con windows xp
el programa solo tiene que mostrar mi nombre y edad

```
.model small
.stack
.data
   saludo   db "Alejandra 24", "$"
 
.code
 
main  proc              ;Inicia proceso
   mov   ax,seg saludo     ;hmm ¿seg?
   mov   ds,ax          ;ds = ax = saludo
 
   mov   ah,09          ;Function(print string)
   lea   dx,saludo         ;DX = String terminated by "$"
   int   21h               ;Interruptions DOS Functions
 
;mensaje en pantalla
 
   mov   ax,4c00h       ;Function (Quit with exit code (EXIT))
   int   21h            ;Interruption DOS Functions
 
main  endp              ;Termina proceso
end main
```

Comment: Si añadieras el código de ejemplo.asm podríamos intentar ayudarte mejor.

Comment: ya lo coloque :)